# How does the EVM read values in the Stack?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, stack

For opcodes like `dup2`, how does the EVM read the stack value that is not at the top of the stack for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1):

The Stack is implemented as part of the client. So let’s say we consider Geth (the most popular client).

In this case, the Stack is simply represented as a list behind the scenes. Literally just a list: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/stack.go#L34-L36

The dup2 instruction is an instruction among what they call the dup  family instructions (just a fancy way of saying: you can have dup with all kinds of numbers like dup2, dup3, and so on).

All that `dupN` does behind the scenes is to take the `N`’th stack element down from the top and push it to the top.

In Go, this is simply implemented as such: Take the `<length of stack> - N`th element (btw. the top of the stack is at index  - 1 — aka the most recent item on the stack is at the *end* of the list since we append, and not prepend to the list/stack).

We can see the literal `dup2` code right here:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/stack.go#L72